# Bootstrap Tabs displaying stacked rather than inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Tabs displaying stacked rather than inline.

What I want (taken from Bootstrap Website):

[image]

What I get (notice the tabs 'Tenants' and 'Landlords' are stacked):

[image]

Bootstrap Code (taken from website):

[image]

My code:

```
<ul class="nav nab-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tenant" aria-controls="tenant" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tenants</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#landlord" aria-controls="landlord" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Landlords</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Tenant panel -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tenant">
      <!-- blah blah giant div -->
  </div>

  <!-- Landlord panel -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="landlord">...</div>
</div>
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What is your ".list-inline" class that you've added doing?

Comment: saw that somewhere online, was an attempt to fix but doesn't do anything. I'll take it out in the question.

Comment: it's `nav-tabs` not `nab-tabs`

Comment: wow, now i feel stupid. thanks Lars

Comment: don't worry bout it, we all feel like a bit of a [nab](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nab) sometimes.

Comment: Dang [nab-bit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dang+nabbit) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo pointed out by @Lars:

"it's `nav-tabs` not `nab-tabs`"